# Which approach is better and why?

Tags: java, grails, closures

Suppose i have a collection of nested custom exception that can be thrown from any where in the controller or the services.

So which of the approach is a better option to adopt ? 
1. use try catch block to catch these exceptions
2. use a method to accept a closure that contains all the business module.

e.g

Approach 1 :

```
 try{
      //call the business logic here
    }catch(CustomException ex){
      // do something
    }
```

Approach 2.

```
Controller.action{
   // call the business logic here.
}
This method will in turn catch all the exceptions in a try catch
like, this action may look like the following

action(Closure closure){
   try{
}
catch(CustomException e)
  // do handling
}
```

Which of the above is architechture vise more correct and is more clean to look.

Comment: Most of the Which & Why question depends on business requirement rather than technical feasibility. Answers for these questions will be driven based on what you would like to achieve.

Comment: the question is just is it good to use try catch at the origin of the request or call a service method  that does just this handling for me

Comment: or is it good to use exceptions at all...

Answer (score 1):

You should consider where and when you want to handle exceptions. Enclose in a try-catch if you can do something about it at that point (i.e. log the error, retry etc.) If there is nothing useful you can do then allow it to bubble up and handle at a higher level. I prefer unchecked to checked exceptions for this reason, as you can choose to handle them when you want to and are not forced to clutter your code with try-catch blocks.

In this case, I would tend to look for exceptions in the controller only and respond accordingly unless there is something specific I can do to handle the exception lower down.

But it does depend on the use case and personal preference. It's definitely important to think about when an exception may occur and how and when you want to deal with it rather than apply a blanket approach to all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

My personnal preference:

- If the system can do something about the Exception (like a retry) : approach1
- If the system can't do anything but report to the user : I use an exception handling method in my Controller, like this [Grails Goodness example](http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2014/05/grails-goodness-exception-methods-in.html?m=1)